# Autocomplete jquery Not working, it shows all data

Tags: jquery, json

I would like to make autocomplete input tag with jquery plugin, However it shows all of the data instead of the search keyword. Below is my html code, js and json source

xml.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQueryUI Auto Complete</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <style>
    .ui-autocomplete-loading {
        background: white url("images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/suggestionBox.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="birds">London matches: </label>
    <input class="content2" id="txtFastQuote" name="txtFastQuote" size="20" ">
</div>

<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">

    <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Suggestion Box.js, where I put my javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtFastQuote").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "countries.json",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.name,
                                    value: item.code
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (a, b, c) {
                            debugger;
                        }
                    });

                },
                minLength: 1
            });
        });
```

My countries.json file

```
[ 
  {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}, 
  {"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"}]
```

Comment: You need to filter the response yourself, based on the provided value of `request`

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand, can you explain more detailed?

Comment: @NitinDhomse where should I put that?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtFastQuote").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.getJSON('data/countries.json', { q: request.term }, function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.destinations, function(item) {
                        return item.name;
                    }));
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: It did not work, it keeps show all data.. If I search Afghanistan, it shows all of the data, instead of afgahanistan only

Comment: {"country":[ 
  {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}, 
  {"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"}, 
  {"name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"}, 
  {"name": "American Samoa", "code": "AS"}, 
  {"name": "AndorrA", "code": "AD"}]} , I had already change data.country in my javascript

Comment: what does q:request.term do?

Comment: request.term is the text you entering to  search

Comment: is it jquery syntax or you defined on your own?. Sorry I really new in jquery